# How to add a cache context from an existing menu?

Tags: 8, caching, breadcrumbs

I want to update my breadcrumb when the menu structure changes. This did not work:

```
$breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route']);
```

Whats the correct way?

Edit: some more context (pun actually intended):

> I have a breadcrumb which adds the menu structure of the current
>   node's menu parents as links. Obviously, when the structure somehow
>   changes, the breadcrumb has to get updated also.

Comment: Can you add in a little more context (no pun intended) as to what you are doing here?  I think this will be beneficial to future readers, but what is going on is a little hard to glean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's:

```
$breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route.menu_active_trails:main']);
```

and

```
$breadcrumb->addCacheTags(['config:system.menu.main']);
```

Comment: See above comment.  I assume you are dealing with the main menu here?

Comment: How did you come to this answer, I'm curious?

Comment: @MPD i loved the pun though :D I have a breadcrumb which adds the menu structure of the current node's parents as links. Obviously, when the structure somehow changes, the breadcrumb has to get updated also. By adding that context it does. The `:main` part must be refactored though since it only works with the main menu then.

Comment: @oknate good question! I've looked into several core classes which implement a breadcrumb. There is path breadcrumb and in it somewhere it adds the following cache: `$breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route']);` and that got me curious. So I took a closer look to the route param and in the docs it says: `route.menu_active_trails:menu_name` and after some try and error I came to this solution :)

Comment: see my updated answer if you might need this